# why get-azureadserviceprincipal can't find service principal?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I just created a service principal using `New-AzADServicePrincipal`.

```
New-AzADServicePrincipal -DisplayName testapp -scope $resourcegroup.ResourceId
```

I can see it created in both app registration and enterprise application.

If I try to find it using `Get-AzureADServicePrincipal` filtered by app ID, I couldn't find it. Using `Get-AzureADApplication` filtered by app ID, I *can* find it.

Why is this?

Comment: If you run the get cmdlet without any filters, can you find it in the list?

Comment: no i can't see it in the list..i thought New-AzADServicePrincipal creates the app registration and also the service principal in the tenant?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the syntax you used for `New-AzADServicePrincipal` and `Get-AzureADServicePrincipal`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the New-AzADServicePrincipal cmdlet does not create the app registration.. At least in our scripts we first create the Application and then the Service Principal.

Comment: Hi @juunas, that's not right, when you do New-AzADServicePrincipal, it of course creates the app registration. you can see the service principal has an app id, if you search for that app ID, you will see the app registration

Comment: Oh is that so? I could be wrong, I've just always created the app object first :)

Answer (score 0):

A few hours later, it populates with Get-AzureADServicePrincipal now..
weird why it couldn't display straightaway, have to wait few hours? but showing straight on portal